# Calling NSURLConnection inside dispatch_async and reading didReceiveResponse in mainRunLoop in iPhone development

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlconnection, nsrunloop, dispatch-async

What I am trying to do is getting response for following method

```
 - (void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response { }
```

after calling this

```
NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
[conn scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
[conn start];
```

inside a

```
dispatch_async();
```

But the `connection` method is not calling. But when I run the `NSURLConnection` code outside the `dispatch_async` it call the method.

What is the reason for that and how can I correct it? 
Is that because `delegate` refers to `self` and `self` refers the the background thread but not the `UIViewController` class itself?

Comment: What thread are you on when calling `dispatch_async` and on what thread do you want to dispatch it?

Comment: which dispatch queue is you using in `dispatch_async()`?

Comment: When I am calling `NSURLConnection` I am inside `dispatch_async()`. By the way by calling `[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(myBgWork) withObject:Nil waitUntilDone:NO];` this and put my `NSURLConnection` code inside `myBgWork` gives me the response for `didReceiveResponse`. But now I am confuse because I feel my background work again calling to main thread and it will slow my application. Is that so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're creating a connection to be scheduled in a loop and started later, make sure to use the rendition of `initWithRequest` with the `startImmediately` parameter set to `NO`. Right now, you're starting the connection twice. And, more significantly, you're starting it before you scheduled it in the main run loop.

To remedy this, specify `startImmediately` as `NO`:

```
NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self startImmediately:NO];
[conn scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
[conn start];
```

---

Having said that, I see no need to dispatch this code to the background queue at all (because `initWithRequest` runs asynchronously and will have no discernible impact on the app performance). The only time I use the above pattern is when I'm wrapping my `NSURLConnection` requests in some custom `NSOperation` subclass (in which case, the above pattern is very useful). But in this case, it is unnecessary.

Comment: Thank yo for the response. I used `dispatch_async()` because I'm having a file zipping process too which will take a considerable time.

Comment: @AnujAroshA Then you can dispatch just that zipping process to a background queue. But there's no point in dispatching the start of the connection to a background queue, especially if you're going to turn around and schedule it in the main run loop (which means all of the delegate methods are called on the main thread, even though you instantiate the connection from a background queue). Even if it didn't run on the main thread, there's no reason not to. Just dispatch that slow zipping code to a background queue.